# Polarization of the Jacobian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, riemann-surfaces

I'm walking towards the Torelli's Theorem.I started from scratch! I did not even know what a divisor was in a Riemann surface. I currently went through Abel's Theorem, theta divisor... Now I am reading the proof of the following theorem:

Theorem 2.25: The theta divisor $\Theta$ of the Jacobian variety $J(R)$, the subvariety $W^{g-1}$ and Riemann's constant are related by following equality:

$\Theta=W^{g-1} + [k]$.

In the reference I'm using [https://www.amazon.com/Advances-Moduli-Translations-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0821821563](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821821563)

After this theorem 2.25 is written: This theorem implies that the polarization of the Jacobian variety 
is given by the line bundle $[W^{g-1}]$.

I need to read about polarization of the Jacobian variety. Right now I have another very good reference *Compact Riemann surfaces*  (Raghavan Narasimhan), But I did not find out about polarization of the Jacobian variety in this book.

I would like references on the subject. Thank you!

Comment: For an expert overview without full details, I strongly recommend Mumford's Curves and their Jacobians.  https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?sts=t&an=mumford&tn=curves+and+their+jacobians&kn=&isbn=  The abstract here will indicate the contents.  https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-46021-3_4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps http://jmilne.org/math/articles/1986c.pdf helps you. Theorem 6.6 is the principal polarisation of the Jacobian.

Comment: Thank you! Any bibliographic indication on the subjects (theta divisor, jacobian variety, riemann's singularity theorem) Torelli's theorem, is welcome!

Comment: The Griffiths-Harris might helps. It has a section on Torelli for curves doing the exact steps you need.